# Looping is not working

Tags: java, android, loops

i am trying to make a loop for all the selected ID, but unfortunately it does not working. only the the 1st Id entered was accepted and do not loop on the next value in the arraylist. here's my code. I don't know where I missed something. Thanks!

```
if (arraylistSelectedConsumerIds != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <arraylistSelectedConsumerIds.size(); i++)

                ConsumerId = arraylistSelectedConsumerIds.get(i);
                databaseAdapter.updateEmailmark(ConsumerId);
                Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"consumer id" + ConsumerId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a basic syntax error to me.

```
if (arraylistSelectedConsumerIds != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i <arraylistSelectedConsumerIds.size(); i++) {

            ConsumerId = arraylistSelectedConsumerIds.get(i);
            databaseAdapter.updateEmailmark(ConsumerId);
            Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this,"consumer id" + ConsumerId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Just add the curly braces for the loop like I did here and make sure you use your IDE to check for further syntax errors.

Comment: Exactly that, otherwise the for loop execute only the first line after it.

Answer (score -1):

You should to debug it. Maybe `arraylistSelectedConsumerIds` is linked to `databaseAdapter`, and size changed when you call `updateEmailmark`. If that's the case, you should store the value first. For example:

```
int listSize = arraylistSelectedConsumerIds.size();
for(int i = 0; i <listSize; i++)
```